# Symfony 6, not able to read legacy session

Tags: php, symfony, session

I have a legacy API application which makes traditional `session_start();` and fills data into `$_SESSION`.
Now I am doing a v2 API with Symfony 6.4, in the same environment, and I want to read data form `$_SESSION`.

I found [Integrating with Legacy Applications](https://symfony.com/doc/6.4/session.html#integrating-with-legacy-applications).
I don't know if the legacy application has a mentioned `own PHP save handler`, I just tried all possible configuration combinations.

```yaml
framework:
    session:
        storage_factory_id: session.storage.factory.php_bridge
```

I removed the `var/cache` & warmed it up.

Result:

- `$_SESSION`: undefined
- `$this->requestStack->getSession()`: Gives a complicated object tree, without legacy session data, but weird Symfony keys with empty arrays `_sf2_attributes`, `_symfony_flashes`.
- `$this->requestStack->getSession()->get('keyInLegacySession')`: null

```yaml
framework:
    session:
        storage_factory_id: session.storage.factory.php_bridge
        handler_id: ~
```

I removed the `var/cache` & warmed it up.

Result: Same as above.

```yaml
framework:
    session:
        storage_factory_id: session.storage.factory.php_bridge
        handler_id: session.handler.native_file
```

I removed the `var/cache` & warmed it up.

Result: Same as above.

I tried to debug as explained in https://stackoverflow.com/a/44145831/4840661, bug legacy and Symfony give the same ini settings.

Any ideas how to read legacy session data in my case with Symfony?

Answer (score 0):

I would do try the following:

You can create a [custom session handler](https://symfony.com/doc/current/session.html#session-proxies) in Symfony.

For example, you create the `CustomNativeSessionStorage` handler and inherit the `NativeSessionStorage` handler. Of course, you can also take other existing handlers and customize them.

In the `CustomNativeSessionStorage::start()` method, you define how and when the session is started or loaded. You can certainly use a part of [NativeSessionStorage::start()](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/97d1624b299d9f0062f87dbc2c27bbf583eb7a5a/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Session/Storage/NativeSessionStorage.php#L121) for this.

The `NativeSessionStorage::start()` method is used to start the session, which you can then control yourself.

```php
namespace App\Session;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\NativeSessionStorage;

class CustomNativeSessionStorage extends NativeSessionStorage
{
    public function start(): bool
    {
        // Here is your logic
        return true;
    }
}
```

```yaml
framework:
    session:
        # ...
        handler_id: App\Session\CustomNativeSessionStorage
```

Comment: I actually had the idea to hardly read the data from `/tmp`, I could use the custom handler approach as you suggested, but still reading hardly from `/tmp`. I would expect that Symfony handles it for me.

Comment: If I use the provided classes, even if I overwrite methods, i run into lifecycle problems every time (calling `start()` to load $_SESSION, causes crash on magic call of `registerBag()`, due to already started). Without provided classes I have to map $_SESSION to bags, which is confusing, plenty of empty methods are needed due to the interface, and the requirement of using AttributeBag for being able to make `$this->requestStack->getSession()->get('..')`. I think I just hack `start_session()` in an auth service, and I wait until I refactor the usage from PHP session, to JWT sending in headers.